# MySQL - How much physical space will be reduced by changing the column type?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5

Lets say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `relationship_status` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and lets say this table have lots of records: 100M

I have 2 possible values to `relationship_status`: 'following' or 'not_following'

since I want to reduce the size of DB (size on hard drive), how would it effect if I would change the `relationship_status` to Boolean instead of varchar(48) (where if can define 0 as not following and 1 as following)?

which column type would you use? tinyint?

Comment: lets say the table has 2 more columns, 1 which is varchar(255) and another one which is DATETIME, lets say I can change both column types to `int(11) unsigned`, how much disk space that would save?

Comment: Here is a link to the storage requirements of each type, you can use the same calculations below to work this out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `TINYINT` would be a good choice. I would suggest not indexing `relationship_status` at all. You should not index `relationship_status` by itself because the index cardinality is 2. The Query Optimizer would never use the index. You could index as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX (relationship_status,user_id);
```

That way, in the worst case, the Query Optimizer would perform an index scan on queries like:

```
SELECT user_id FROM my_table WHERE relationship_status = 1;
SELECT relationship_status,COUNT(1) statuscount
FROM my_table GROUP BY relationship_status;
```

The EXPLAIN plan should improve in that sorting and temp table usage would be minimized or eliminated.

Now concerning diskspace, let's compute the savings in space. First, What is the length of each string?

```
mysql> select length('following') followlength,length('not_following') notfollowlength;
+--------------+-----------------+
| followlength | notfollowlength |
+--------------+-----------------+
|            9 |              13 |
+--------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Each VARCHAR has an additional byte for tracking string length. The values are really 10 and 14. That gets ignored since you are shrinking the field to 1 byte. If you collapse `relationship_status` to TINYINT, the savings would be as follows

```
SELECT
    BB SavingsBytes,
    BB/POWER(1024,1) SavingsKB,
    BB/POWER(1024,2) SavingsMB,
    BB/POWER(1024,3) SavingsGB
FROM
(
    SELECT
        fcount*length('following')+ncount*length('not_following') BB
    FROM
        (
            SELECT COUNT(1) fcount FROM my_table
            WHERE relationship_status='following'
        ) F,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(1) ncount FROM my_table
            WHERE relationship_status='not_following'
        ) N
);
```

Since the the number of rows is about 100M, the Savings in Diskspace would have to be between 900M and 1.3G.

### **UPDATE 2012-08-23 13:00 EDT**

To answer your comment

> lets say the table has 2 more columns, 1 which is varchar(255) and another one which is DATETIME, lets say I can change both column types to int(11) unsigned, how much disk space that would save?

First of all, a `DATETIME` is 8 bytes and `INT(11)` is 4 bytes. Since 8 - 4 = 4, your savings would be 4 bytes per row. For the table, `SELECT COUNT(1)*4 FROM my_table;`

Now, the varchar(255) field. As I mentioned before, a varchar has an extra byte for length management. Sum up all the lengths of all the varchar fields and add the row count (the extra from field on every row) and subtract 4 bytes times the row count.

Putting the DATETIME and VARCHAR calculations together, you get this

```
SELECT
    BB SavingsBytes,
    BB/POWER(1024,1) SavingsKB,
    BB/POWER(1024,2) SavingsMB,
    BB/POWER(1024,3) SavingsGB
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        (VarCharBytes - (RowCount * 3)) BB
    FROM
    (
        SELECT SUM(LENGTH(varcharfield)) VarCharBytes
        FROM my_table
    ) A,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) RowCount FROM my_table) T
);
```

Comment: is TINYINT better then BIT(1) in this case?

Comment: why wouldn't you index the table?

Comment: Updated my answer concerning indexing...

Comment: @Ran they are both the same storage size (1 byte)

Comment: Thanks!! and how do you think the data size would change if changing the other column types (please see my comment on the question)?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use a BIT(1) data type and change the column name to "following" just so it makes logical sense.

The space used by your current design is such (using the length of the text NOT_FOLLOWING which is 13 bytes):

> (13 * 100,000,000) / (1024 ^ 3) => 1.21GB approx.

Using a bit field would use the following space:

> (1 * 100,000,000) / (1024 ^ 3) => 0.093GB

This would give you a space saving of:

> 1.21 - 0.093 => 1.12GB approx

I hope this helps you.